# Java: How to avoid "method not applicable for the arguments" error

Tags: java, generics

I realize this type of question has been asked countless times, but I haven't found an answer that seems to address and/or explain what 1) I'm doing wrong and 2) what I need to do to get it right.

I have an application where I'm trying to manage a collection of queues. The users of the queue manager will ask for a queue by providing a unique ID and the manager will return the queue if it's already being managed, or create a new queue (via reflection) and return it if it has not yet been created.

I've coded the queue manager to use Java generics and am running into an issue that I don't understand, nor how to correct the problem.

Here is the queue manager:

```
public class QueueManager<T extends MessageType, C extends BlockingQueue<T>> {

  private Map<UUID, C> queueMap;

  public void removeQueue(UUID id) {
    queueMap.remove(id);
  }

  public C getQueue(Class<C> clazz, UUID id) {
    if (!queueMap.containsKey(id)) {
      queueMap.put(id, constructQueue(clazz));
    }

    return queueMap.get(id);
  }

  private C constructQueue(Class<C> clazz) {
    C result = null;

    try {
      Constructor<C> constructor = clazz.getDeclaredConstructor();
      result = constructor.newInstance();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | InstantiationException
        | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
      // handle exception
    }

    return result;
  }

}
```

Code that uses the queue manager:

```
public class QueueingListener<T extends MessageType> implements MessageListener<T> {

  private QueueManager<T, BlockingQueue<T>> queueMgr = new QueueManager<>();
...
  @Override
  public void handleMessage(T message) {
...
      queueMgr.getQueue(LinkedBlockingQueue.class,
          message.getMessageHeader().getUUID());
...
  }
```

The code complains with a compilation error:

```
The method getQueue(Class<BlockingQueue<T>>, UUID) in the type QueueManager<T,BlockingQueue<T>> is not applicable for the arguments (Class<LinkedBlockingQueue>, UUID)
```

Could someone please explain what is wrong here and what I need to do instead?

I'd really like to know where to find a really good tutorial on Java generics. I've looked at many sources, but they seem to cover only the basics to get someone going and don't cover more advanced concepts and finer details.

Comment: Why don't you just pass a `Supplier<BlockingQueue>` to `getQueue` rather than the class and then constructing it via reflection?

Comment: @daniu Please elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why care about the type of queues that are managed, and why not just pass a `Supplier<BlockingQueue>` to the getter?

```
public class QueueManager<T extends MessageType> {

    private Map<UUID, BlockingQueue<T>> queueMap;

    public void removeQueue(UUID id) {
      queueMap.remove(id);
    }

    public BlockingQueue<T> getQueue(UUID id, Supplier<BlockingQueue<T>> createQueue) {
        return queueMap.computeIfAbsent(id, k -> createQueue.get());
    }

    // let's add a default while we're at it 
    public BlockingQueue<T> getQueue(UUID id) {
        return getQueue(id, () -> new ArrayBlockingQueue<T>(50));
    }
}
```

That would make the call

```
queueMgr.getQueue(message.getMessageHeader().getUUID(), LinkedBlockingQueue::new);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll summate the important parts of this code for the point I'm going to make:

```
public class QueueManager<T extends MessageType, C extends BlockingQueue<T>> {
  public C getQueue(Class<C> clazz, UUID id) {
    if (!queueMap.containsKey(id)) {
      queueMap.put(id, constructQueue(clazz));
    }

    return queueMap.get(id);
  }
}
```

Note here that C could be any class extending BlockingQueue when initially creating an instance of this class. However, once you create this object, C is set as some type of specific class. You later call the following code:

```
private QueueManager<T, BlockingQueue<T>> queueMgr = new QueueManager<>();
```

The line above defines C as a 'BlockingQueue'.

```
queueMgr.getQueue(LinkedBlockingQueue.class, message.getMessageHeader().getUUID());
```

However, in this line, you pass in a completely different object. **LinkedBlockingQueue** implements BlockingQueue, yes, but the Class objects for both respectively are completely different, and they are **not** specified by your class description. What you're looking for is a class of something that **extends C** in your method signature. Thus, the remedy to this error would be to modify your getQueue() method as such:

```
  public <X extends C> C getQueue(Class<X> clazz, UUID id) {
    if (!queueMap.containsKey(id)) {
      queueMap.put(id, constructQueue(clazz));
    }

    return queueMap.get(id);
  }
```

There is a subtle, but important, syntactic difference here that I hope I've explained clearly. You would also modify constructQueue() in a similar way. :)